# Remove references to __gnu_mcount_nc from precompiled Linux kernel module

Tags: linux, assembly, profiling, arm

I have a binary Linux kernel module for some peripheral device.
It works fine but it uses profiling, which support I removed from
the Kernel for performance reasons. I cannot recompile the module
because its 3rd party proprietary software and I do not have access
to the source code. I only possess the object files (*.o) needed to
link the driver to my Linux Kernel version.

Is it possible to process .ko file and remove the jumps to
`__gnu_mcount_nc` function? I was thinking to change the opcode
from `bl <__gnu_mcount_nc>` to `mov r8,r8`, but its hard to achieve due
to fact that every branch to external function has `ebfffffe` opcode.
This lead me to relocations topic which I want to avoid. I'm looking
for some trivial solution.

```
Disassembly of section .text:

00000000 <some_func1>:
       0:       e92d4000        push    {lr}
       4:       ebfffffe        bl      18e0 <__gnu_mcount_nc>
       8:       e3a00001        mov     r0, #1
       c:       e12fff1e        bx      lr

00000010 <some_func2>:
      10:       e92d4000        push    {lr}
      14:       ebfffffe        bl      18e0 <__gnu_mcount_nc>
      18:       e3a00001        mov     r0, #1
      1c:       e12fff1e        bx      lr

00000020 <some_func3>:
      20:       e92d4038        push    {r3, r4, r5, lr}
      24:       e92d4000        push    {lr}
      28:       ebfffffe        bl      18e0 <__gnu_mcount_nc>
      2c:       e1a04001        mov     r4, r1
      30:       e59f3038        ldr     r3, [pc, #56]   ; 70 <some_func3+0x50>
      34:       e5905034        ldr     r5, [r0, #52]   ; 0x34
...
```

Target board is based on armv7-a architecture and Cortex-A9 core.

**Edit:**

**Question 1:**  `__mcount_loc` contains relative pointers to `<__gnu_mcount_nc>`. How Kernel know during fixuping the addresses what section the pointer is relative to?

**Question 2:**  It seems that "hacked" kernel module does not work. Issuing insmod .ko trigger error message:

> insmod: can't insert 'some_driver.ko': unknown symbol in module or
>   invalid parameter

Do I have to remove the symbol __gnu_mcount_nc from some section? Even if its not used by now?

Looking for some ideas, thanks.

Comment: Rather than trying to modify the code, you'll want to look at the relocation table, as it contains the actual kernel symbols used by the module.

Comment: Sorry but i don't get it. I know what symbols are used in module and I want to keep them all except profiling one: __gnu_mcount_nc

Comment: If you do `objdump -r <name_of_object_file>` on the command line, you'll see a list of all the relocations. Basically, when the module is loaded, the kernel will scan through the relocation list and replace all of those `ebfffffe` instructions with jumps to actual functions. The idea is you can look through the relocations yourself to find anything that refers to `__gnu_mcount_nc` and remove those relocation entries (you'll also need to modify the instruction it refers to to be a `nop` or equivalent).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should recompile your kernel with FTRACE support and enable `CONFIG_DYNAMIC_FTRACE`.

You don't need to worry about it affecting performance - unless tracing is actually enabled, all calls to `__gnu_mcount_nc` [will be NOPped out](http://lhwdb.org/cfg/DYNAMIC_FTRACE) by the kernel loader. This is what the `__mcount_loc` section (in the final .ko) for - it has a list of all locations of the `bl __gnu_mcount_nc` calls in the binary.

Comment: I said "performance reason", but I had also size of the Kernel itself on my mind - its roughly **170kB** smaller without FTRACE support. I have very limited Flash memory and I'd love to keep FTRACE disabled.

So I stayed with concept to change all `BL <__gnu_mcount_nc>` to `"mov r8, r8"`. I took all relative pointers to `__gnu_mcount_nc` from `__mcount_loc` and swaped the instructions. This succeeded - at least from what I see after disassemble the Kernel module.